# Schedule java timer at a variable rate

Tags: java, timer

```
int tickRate = 1950;
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override public void run() { Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(tickRate > 750) { tickRate -= 100; }
                else tickRate = 750;
                new Egg(gridPane);
            }}); } };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1000, tickRate);
```

How can I make my timer change its rate dynamically?

Comment: Don't use `scheduleAtFixedRate`. Use `schedule` and at the end of each task schedule the next execution with whatever delay you want. So each task spawns a new task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Comment by Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68005252/schedule-java-timer-at-a-variable-rate/68005893#comment120198146_68005252) is correct: Use `schedule` rather than `scheduleAtFixedRate`. During each execution of the task, have the task schedule the next execution.

And, another thing: The `Timer`/`TimerTask` classes have been supplanted by the Executors framework as noted in the Javadoc. I suggest you learn about using a `ScheduledExecutorService`. Read *The Java Tutorials* by Oracle, and search Stack Overflow to learn more.